# Python: variable is undefined when calling function containing the variable

Tags: python

I just started my first programming class a few weeks ago and I'm embarrassed to say I'm very stuck. We had to create a program that (in my Professor's words):

> Simulate the roll of two dice. Use a randomly generated integer to represent the roll of each die in a function named point. Return the combined value of a roll. Use a loop in main to roll the dice five times and report each result.

So, I did my best and keep getting the same issue where it is telling me my variable `total` is not defined, even though I'm calling the function which contains the variable.

I submitted the below code to my professor, who in turn responded:

> The dice program is close. Return the total of a roll. Call point in main and capture the returned value for printing.

So he is saying to call the function `point` in my `main` function (which, at least I think, I am) but it still won't read my vital variable to finishing this.

```
import random

min=1
max=6



def main():
  for roll in range(5):
    point()
    print(total)


def point():

  roll=random.randint(min, max)
  roll2=random.randint(min, max)
  total=roll+roll2
  return total

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `main` function, this line:

```
point()
```

does not make `total` available in the current scope.  Instead, it simply calls the function `point` and then discards its return value.

You need to capture this return value by assigning it to a variable named `total`:

```
def main():
  for roll in range(5):
    ################
    total = point()
    ################
    print(total)
```

Now, when you do `print(total)`, `total` will be defined and equal to the value of `point()`.

Comment: Grrr I knew it'd be something simple! Thank you so much!! The explanation was perfect as well =D

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference a variable that only exists within the scope of the point() function.  But you don't need to since you return the value anyway.

Try this.

```
from random import randint
def rollD6():
    return randint(1,6)

def point():
    return rollD6()+rollD6()

def main():
    for roll in range(5):
        print point()

main()
```